# Laravel form with <div> tags in the middle

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I am trying to use a form with div tags in the middle. However, it doesnt seem to work, the form works fine when used without them. Is there any way to stylise the form and use it ?

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'ProductController@store', 'method' => 'POST', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}
<div class="centre col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 ">
  <h2>Product</h2>
  {{Form::text('', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Product'])}}
</div>
<div>
  <div class="section3  ">
    <div class="container centre">
      {{Form::submit('Submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: you can use form tag without `Form` facade

Comment: what is purpose of `<div>`

Comment: @HoàngĐăng to centre the elements and also make columns.

Comment: you mean your css is broken when inserting a div tag

Comment: @HoàngĐăng the form doesnt submit when i use div tags and press the button. Otherwise is fine

Comment: all div tag above or only for div tag without class

Comment: @HoàngĐăng for all div tags

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162471/discussion-between-hoang-dng-and-joe-m).

Answer (score 1):

You have some unwanted `</div>` in your code which leads form to close in a wrong place, fix the `<div>` and it will start working again. Basically, this is an error due to the non-well-formatted code.

```
<div>
        {!! Form::open(['action' => 'ProductController@store', 'method' => 'POST', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}

   <div class="centre col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 ">
            <h2>Product</h2>
            {{Form::text('', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Product'])}}
    </div>
     <div class="section3  ">
        <div class="container centre">

            {{Form::submit('Submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And don't forget to add name and other parameters in your code to make your form worthy.

```
{{Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Product'])}}
```

Answer (score 0):

first the div tag is not proprly closed ..you have two unwanted  tag in first div . 
you can style according to your design need .

.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="well">

{!! Form::open(['action' => 'ProductController@store', 'class' => 'form-inline' , 'method' => 'POST', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}

<fieldset>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('product', 'Product:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-
       label']) !!}
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            {!! Form::text('product', $value = null, ['class' => 'form-
             control', 'placeholder' => 'product']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Submit Button -->
        <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
            {!! Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn  btn-info '] ) !!}
         </div>
        </div>

</fieldset>

{!! Form::close()  !!}

  </div>
</div>
```

you can use bootsrap html form for easy and better design since they have different form-class for different design .

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms.asp

if u find this helpful

Answer (score 0):

The form close tag should be at the same depth as the form open tag:

without them. Is there any way to stylise the form and use it ?

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'ProductController@store', 'method' => 'POST', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}
<div>
    <div>

       <div class="centre col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 ">
                <h2>Product</h2>
                {{Form::text('product', $value=null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Product'])}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="section3  ">
        <div class="container centre">

            {{Form::submit('Submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```